# How to execute process in Mono with nohup?

Tags: c#, linux, mono, sh, nohup

I'm looking to execute a process in Mono (C#) in a Linux box, but I need it to keep running after my .exe has exited. I'm trying to use nohup to do this, but so far have not had any success. This is my code right now:

```
void Execute(string command, string commandPath, string arguments, bool nohup = false)
{
   ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
                        {
                            FileName = nohup ? "sh" : Path.Combine(commandPath, script),
                            Arguments = nohup ? "nohup " + Path.Combine(commandPath, script) + " " + arguments + " &" : arguments,
                            UseShellExecute = false,
                            CreateNoWindow = true,
                            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                            RedirectStandardError = true,
                            RedirectStandardInput = true,
                            UserName = System.Environment.UserName
                        };

        using (Process process = Process.Start(startInfo))
                        { // Monitor for exit}
}
```

So I'm checking the nohup parameter and if it is true I execute a shell and send the full command (ex: `nohup /path/to/my/command <args> &`). I'm getting an error that says `/path/to/my/command cannot execute binary file`.

The other thing I have thought of is opening the sh process and then sending the full nohup command to the Standard Input, but to do this I'd have to refactor quite a bit of code, so if there is a way to do what I want without this, I'd go that route.

So... what is the best way to execute a process in C# in a Linux environment (Mono) that uses nohup to stay alive after the parent process has died?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm getting an error that says /path/to/my/command cannot execute
>   binary file.

In this case, I would change the CreateNoWindow to true, do not redirect IO and see what you are getting in the created shell in order to debug that...

As far are creating a background process, one way is to create daemon and have a method to read/write info to it (network port, file logs, etc..), but simply starting a background task like you trying works fine.

Here is an quick hack/example using your code as a starting point. Instead of using a Process, I just system exec the command, a find in this case. As that runs in the background, I run a Process for word counting the number of lines that are in the log file after 1 second and when exiting you get a prompt to kill that background find process...

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

    namespace nohub.process.exec
    {
        class MainClass
        {

            [DllImport ("libc")]
            private static extern int system (string exec);

            private static string logfile = Path.GetTempFileName ();

            static void Execute (string command, string commandPath, string arguments, bool nohup = false)
            {
                if (!nohup) {
                    var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo () {
                        FileName = Path.Combine (commandPath, command),
                        Arguments = arguments,
                        UseShellExecute = false,
                        CreateNoWindow = true,
                        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                        RedirectStandardError = true,
                        RedirectStandardInput = true,
                        UserName = System.Environment.UserName
                    };

                    using (Process process = Process.Start (startInfo)) { // Monitor for exit}
                        process.WaitForExit ();
                        using (var output = process.StandardOutput) {
                            Console.Write ("Results: {0}", output.ReadLine ());
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    system ("nohup " + Path.Combine (commandPath, command) + " " + arguments + " 2>&1 > " + logfile + " & "); 
                }

            }

            public static void Main (string[] args)
            {
                Console.WriteLine ("Hello Stack Overflow");
                Console.WriteLine ("Temp file: {0}", logfile);
                Execute ("find", "", "/", true);
                Thread.Sleep (1000);
                Execute ("wc", "", "-l " + logfile, false);
                Console.Write ("\nLet find continue? [y/n]");
                if ((Console.ReadKey (false)).KeyChar == 'y')
                    system ("killall find");
            }
        }
    }
```